# How come 2 MOSFET chips are needed in protection circuits?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, battery-operated

Like those [here](http://alphaphotography.smugmug.com/photos/i-fvpRmzJ/0/L/i-fvpRmzJ-L.jpg), the protection boards have at least 2 MOSFET chip (AO8814). Does anyone know why so many (4 fets) are needed?

Comment: Because you need to be able to control current bidirectionally.

Comment: But the AO8814 (which is what they use) is already a bi-directional load switch. How come another one is still needed?

Comment: They look to be completely in parallel, including control, from the layout. So they act as a single larger MOSFET pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the switches are connected in parallel (as indicated in one of the comments, ie the two SOURCES are linked via the PCB) it is for one of two reasons

1. Redundancy. If one FET can handle the current and FMEA calls for two... two in parallel double's the current capability - NOTE this is a dormant failure
2. Current capability. Two in parallel will permit more current

Two sets of paralleled FET's would imply a disconnect topology to isolate the +VE and the -VE from the supply

Answer (score 6):

MOSFETs have a parasitic body diode which is an inherent part of their construction. If a single FET is used to protect the cell then (depending on which way around the FET is connected) the body diode will conduct either during charging or discharging.

Placing two MOSFETs back to back prevents this undesired action, as one body diode will always be reverse biased no matter which direction the current tries to flow.

[image]

Comment: But each chip contains 2 fets, so there're 4 fets. Each pair is connected in parallel too.